# Hello, I am needing some help to hexdump a .bin file that a python program created

Tags: python, pythoninterpreter

I am following Ben Eaters tutorial on the 6502 computer and I'm completely lost on the python programming stuff. I have a little bit of programming knowledge, but not enough to understand which programs he is swithcing between.  Here is the link to the video I'm referring to (around the 9:40 mark): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yl8vPW5hydQ&list=PLowKtXNTBypFbtuVMUVXNR0z1mu7dp7eH&index=2

I've created my "makerom.py" program in Visual Studio Code and it appears I was able to run it via the CMD prompt. But when I try to hex dump from there it doesn't work.

Here is my python program:

```
rom = bytearray([0xea] * 32768)

with open("rom.bin", "wb") as out_file:
    out_file.write(rom);
```

I've created my "makerom.py" program in Visual Studio Code and it appears I was able to run it via the CMD prompt. But when I try to hex dump from there it doesn't work.

Comment: Define “Doesn’t work”

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Too many questions to ask to clarify what you are asking. I would use Python for Windows if you're on Windows and then call `> python.exe YourScriptName.py` from within PowerShell. If you're on Linux just use your `bash` terminal and call `$ python YourScriptName.py`.

Your program above works. To check the file that it creates, navigate to the same directory that you ran the script from, and you should find a `rom.bin` file. If you don't see that exact file, your program either didn't work or likely didn't run. But if it's there than your script at least created the file. So then, if you want to see what's inside, if you're in Linux you can run `$ xxd rom.bin` or hexdump. If you're in Windows you can use PowerShell's `> Format-Hex .\rom.bin` to confirm the data was written to the file.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I should have asked what the proper command is to read out the .bin file. But you answered my question. I am in Windows so > Format-Hex .\rom.bin worked perfectly to check the contents of the file. I also tried the same command inside the terminal in Visual Code Studio and it worked there too. Is that terminal the same as using Windows Powershell?